# Convert angular sass project to scss

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular7

I kicked off my Angular 7 project with sass instead of scss, is there a way to convert all the files to scss from the command line? And update the references in all the .ts files?

Comment: you want to change the file extension or you want to convert the syntax?

Comment: looking for a built-in way to do it with angular-cli...change all the files, including package.json, *.ts, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all your files extension using the following command in window machine

`forfiles /S /M *.sass /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.scss"`

If you want to change the `ts` references, you can use vs code search / replace.